# Unexpected output with HashMap

Tags: java, collections

CODE:

```
public class Puzzle23{
    void Puzzle23(){
        map1.put(String1, "1");
        map1.put(String2, "2");
    }

    private final NewMap map1 = new NewMap();
    private static final String String1 = new String("J2eeSig");
    private static final String String2 = new String("J2eeSig");

    public static void main(final String args[]){
        final Puzzle23 p22 = new Puzzle23();
        final Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap();

        map2.put(String1, "1");
        map2.put(String2, "2");
        System.out.println(p22.map1.size() == map2.size() ? true : false);
        p22.map1.remove(new String(String1));
        map2.remove(new String(String2));
        System.out.println(p22.map1.size() == map2.size() ? true : false);
    }

    class NewMap extends IdentityHashMap<String, String>{
        public void put(final String... values){
            super.put(values[0], values[1]);
        }

        public int size(){
            return super.size() + 1 - 1 / 1 * 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Result:-

```
false
true
```

Expected Result:-

```
true
true
```

Why???

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant

Comment: So amazing, using IdentityHashMap and labeling the question as HashMap. Know your data structures! Funniest part is that people actually like the question and the quintessential question 'Why???' (w/ multiple questions markz)

Answer (score 6):

it's because of use `NewMap` is `IdentityHashMap`. Check documentation where is said

> This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.

**EDIT:**
Anyway I found a error in your code. `void Puzzle23()` is not constructor it's a method. Constructor have to be defined without return value (e.g. `Puzzle23()`). So you never fill `map1`. When you fix this you realize that your output is `false` `false` because of `IdentityHashMap`. When you switch `map1` to `HashMap` output will be `true` `true` as you expected. Anyway check documentation of `IdentityHashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

`p22.map1.remove(new String(String1));` will not remove anything because `NewMap` is a subclass of `IdentityHashMap`.

*Update*

I was wrong

1) First error here is `void` method disguised as constructor. That's why `p22.map1` is always empty.

2) Second one is a `NewMap` which is `IdentityHashMap`. After 2 strings is added to it its size becomes 2 because while this strings are equal they are not identical (`==`).

3) `p22.map1.remove(new String(String1));` will not do anything as I said earlier.

Comment: when map1 has nothing and when i try to remove from the map, won't it throw an error??

Comment: No, map will not do anything is such case.

Answer (score 2):

`IdentityHashMap` uses `==` where ordinary `HashMap` uses `.equals()`. See [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html).

Comment: This **and** it uses `System.identityHashCode()` where the `HashMap` uses `.hashCode()`.